# Prevent ModelState.IsValid from validating attached entities?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, modelstate, modelstatedictionary

Is there a way to override `ModelState.IsValid`?

Some of the entities to be validated are just attached entities, so all the fields except the ID are not to be validate as the entity is in state `Unchanged`.

Is there a way to do this?
Has anyone faced this issue before?

**Update**

Say I have the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveEntity(MyEntity entity)
{
    var isValid = ModelState.IsValid; //false
}
```

Since the model validates all properties and all descendant properties of `entity`, there has to be a way to check on each entity of those descendants, whether it's attached to the context, and if it is, remove error from `ModelState`, something like the following:

```
public ActionResult TryValidateDetachedModel(MyEntity entity, DbContext context)
{
    foreach (var ms in ModelState.Where(ms => ms.Value.Errors.Any()).ToArray())            
    // should iterate over something like GetAllEntityTypesMetadata()
    {
        var entity = GetEntityFromMetadata(ms);
        if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Unchanged)
        {
             ms.Value.Errors.Clear();                
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do in the above pseudo code is to check the entities in the validation chain, and if one of them is attached as `Unchanged`, skip validation / remove its errors.

Right now I have to do it hard-coded manually by checking `ModelState.Key`, I'm looking for a more generic and efficient way.

Comment: Why do you bind to EF object, not designated view models?

Comment: I'm using POCO entities, so it makes no difference.

Comment: Obviously it makes a difference, because with dedicated view models you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: OK, assume you're right. Currently I can't afford to recreate view-models for all the models in my domain. Can you think of a solution that incorporates interaction with a provided `DbContext` to see what entities are attached as `Unchanged` and skip validation / remove errors for them?

Comment: Ok. I am not really sure what you are asking for. How is it possible, that entities are attached to DbContext after binding? Maybe you can write some king of `ModelBinder`, that checks state and ignore validation when entity is unchanged, but I am not really sure what you are asking for.

Comment: No. I have another method that automatically attaches the relevant associated FKs to the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear all errors use next

`ModelState.Clear();`

regards

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to ensure the validation only applies to the current entity:

```
        foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
            if (key.Split('.').Length > 2)
                ModelState[key].Errors.Clear();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

The check for the occurrences of `.` means: if the modelstate key is something like `currentDTO.relatedDTO.field` then that validation error is ignored (cleared). If it's just `id` or `currentDTO.validateThisField`, then it doesn't get cleared.